# Generate unique download link for a PDF file

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdf

Hello everybody I'm new here please be friendly and don't get angry cause I'm a beginner.

To introduce you:

First I generated a `pdf` and save it after the user bought the file in a protected folder on my server. Than I save the path to this file with an id in my database.

Second have a php file where I show the user contents/entrys from a database like a download link for the file.

My link looks like this:

```
<a href="http://my-website.de/download?link=<?php echo $row["url_to_my_file"] ?>" target="_blank">Download you file</a>
```

When the user clicks on it he'll be redirected to my download.php where I get the url and send the user the download:

```
$my_file = file_get_contents($_GET['link']);
$size = strlen($my_file);
$file_name = 'My_file_name.pdf';

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
echo $my_file;
```

It works all fine but I have a big problem. When the user right clicks on the link he can see the path where the file is and he can download the file just like his mind (and not mine) and also when I lock the site where he can download the file because he know the download link.

No I get the idea to generate a `md5` string and save it in my database when the user clicks on **Download**. That's my approach:

```
//Generate unique download key
$key = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
//Insert into my database
$sql = "INSERT INTO download_keys (md5_key, expired, download_link) 
    VALUES ('$key', false, '$url')";
```

Seacond give the user a new link:

```
<a href="http://my-website.de/download?link='$key'" target="_blank">Download you file</a>
```

But I cant do this in my file where I show the user the files and don't know how to deal with more than one file?

This is my new download.php

```
$key = $_GET['key'];

$sql = "SELECT download_link FROM download_keys WHERE '$key' = md5_key AND expired = 'false'";
//Check if sql is empty or not
if (mysql_num_rows($sql)==0) {
    echo "No file found or key expired!";
} else {
    $link = $row["download_link"];
}
$sql = "UPDATE download_link SET expired = 'true' WHERE '$key' = md5_key";
```

At the end I change the expire value to true so when the user want to download the file with this link again it don't works.

**Whats the right way to implement this unique file download function so that the user just see the key and not the path?**

So all in all: I want to make a secret download link which the user can use only one. To download the file again he has do click the download button on the site even if he know the url

Thank you for your help! I hope you understan my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Since you are using a php file to send the pdf file to the user, the user cannot directly link to the pdf file, only to the php file with a parameter. If you implement some checks based on the parameter supplied to the php file, you can restrict how long a document is available for download. You seem to have all the components. So, what is your question?

Comment: That's so complicated don't know what you mean :S

Comment: @Shadow How can I implement these checks? The user should be able to download the file all the time but only from the download site (by clicking the download link). So when I lock the site the user can't download the file anymore even if he know the link

Comment: Just simply do not share the direct link with the customer, just the randomly generated parameter. Download.php will look up the fiel's location from the database based on the parameter. That's all. You can implement any further checks into the download.php

Comment: @Shadow okay understand no to hide the link. But that don't clear the problem that the user can download the file from everywhere and not only from my special site hmm :S

Comment: What do you mean that a user can download it from anywhere? The user can only fownliad the content through your dowload.php, not from any location.

Comment: @Shadow Yes, but when he has the download link from the url in the browser he can do you understand? And when I set the download link display: none; and he has the link in his browser history he can open the file too

Comment: So what? He has purchased the document. If you want to implement time restriction or user authentication, then go ahead, you can implement all these in the download.php You can also implement restrictions on how many times a user can download a given content.

Comment: @Shadow I got the solution by hard thinking. Thanks for your thinking approaches

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, do you mean how to display the link as `"http://my-website.de/download?link=baksjcbasduo123231sdsad"` instead of `"http://my-website.de/download?link=baksjcbasduo123231sdsad.php"` ?

If that's the case:
First, You'll need to create an `.htaccess` file

Then put this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^http://my-website.de/download/(.*)$ http://my-website.de/download?link=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: No. I want to implement the md5 key creation and don't know how I can do this. I just have the document download without the md5 secret download link thing. Actualy the user klicks on download and get directly to my download.php with the path to the file in the url but I will display the md5 key instead of my url.

Comment: 1. User clicks download
2. User get a md5 key and will be redirected with **this key in the url** to the database insert with the url and the key
3. Than the user gets redirected to the download page where the select from db give the user the the matching downloadlink from the db table according to his url in the browser

Comment: So all in all: I want to make a secret download link which the user can use only one. To download the file again he has do click the download button on the site even if he know the url